# Python findSpark and PySpark not working. Displays IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pyspark, linux-mint, index-error

I installed findspark and PySpark following a couple of methods. I'm using Python 3.6, java jdk 11.0. I did add to the .bashrc file the following 2 lines of code:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/jbustost/.local/bin
export SPARK_HOME=/home/jbustost/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
```

I have installed Jupyter Notebook, which runs fine but this happens when I try to use findspark.

```
import findspark
findspark.find() # out[2]:'/home/jbustos/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7'
findspark.init() # it crashes here. below is the traceback.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-5f9243a09cec> in <module>
----> 1 findspark.init()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    133     # add pyspark to sys.path
    134     spark_python = os.path.join(spark_home, 'python')
--> 135     py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, 'lib', 'py4j-*.zip'))[0]
    136     sys.path[:0] = [spark_python, py4j]
    137 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction? What am I missing? I'm trying to install this in linux mint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Spark 2.4.x supports JDK 11 yet. I could find a [ticket](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SPARK-2017) for adding Java 11 support but it's still in open state. So, I'd suggest you to go with JDK 8 for now.

Apart from that, you need two more things.

1. Need to add the `$SPARK_HOME/bin` to `PATH`.
2. Need to add pyspark driver options for linking jupyter with pyspark.

Can you please try adding the following to bashrc?

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/jbustost/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:/home/jbustost/.local/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

You need to execute `source ~/.bashrc` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! It found a way to make it work and will be posting it later on. Thanks again!

Comment: @JorgeBustosTorres, any update on your resolution for this question?